# Nest JS differentiate 2 distinct routes of the same controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have a Nest JS application with 2 routes that simply returns the data(preferences) from the database.

I want to create 2 routes:

1. List item preferences: /api/items
2. List feature preferences: /api/features

**I'm new to NestJS. These 2 routes should be under one module. Is this achievable?**

**The 2nd route works but I get an error saying 404 Not Found.**

```
@Module({
  controllers: ['PreferenceController'],
  providers: ['PreferenceService']
})
```

```
@Controller()
export class PreferenceController{
    constructor(private readonly preferenceService: PreferenceService) {}

    @Get('preference/:x/:y/:z')
    getItem(@Param() param) {
        return this.preferenceService.getItem(param);
    }

    @Get(':id')
    getFeature(@Param() param) {
        return this.preferenceService.getFeature(param);
    }
}
```

```
routes = [
   path: '/api',
   children: [
     {
       path: '/items',
       module: 'PreferenceModule'
     },
     { 
       path: '/features',
       module: 'PreferenceModule'
     }
   ]
]
```